# How to use workarounds for a broken LCD screen? Is there such a thing as valid aspect ratios?

Tags: windows, display, resolution

My laptop's 1920x1080 screen has been damaged and about 150 of the leftmost columns are not working. It will be a few weeks before I can replace it, so I would like to change my settings so it doesn't use those columns (I'm on Windows 10, BTW).

Ideally, I'd like to have a 1770x1080 resolution with an offset of 75px to the right from the center, which means only those columns would be cropped.

I tried using the tools suggested on both answers to [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153038/how-to-change-screen-resolution-and-the-size-of-items-using-command-line-program), but had similar errors on unsupported/invalid settings.

My guess is that I cannot pass these settings as loosely as I'd like, but I could not pinpoint exactly what rules they need to follow.

Any hints on how this should be done or even if there's another better approach for the problem is very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you have another monitor which you could attach to the computer until it can be repaired?

Comment: No, I don't. Not even a TV. This laptop is all the hardware I have.

Comment: If you right-click the taskbar and make sure that "Unlock the taskbar" is *not* checked, can you then drag the taskbar to the right edge of the screen? Then you can resize windows so you can see all the content. You will have to run everything in a window, not full-screen, but at least it will be usable.

Comment: I already use the taskbar on the right size even with a working screen. For now, I have set windows to 1680x1050 using the settings app, but this still leaves a few broken columns being used and a lot from the right and a few lines from the bottom goes to waste.

Comment: I have an older Dell 15" monitor you can use-have, but I don't think the cable will reach  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have researched this topic a lot, and sadly their doesn't seem to be any fully elegant solution (No software that does only what you want). However, these are some slightly clunky fixes:

1. Create a Host->Host remote desktop connection. Open a chrome tab and search for chrome remote desktop connection. Install chrome remote desktop connection on your device. Then, remote into your host device as you would a client computer. Resize the chrome window to fit the preferred area of screen. (only tested in linux).
2. Use magnifier on Windows as [discussed on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/1xkx2h/force_windows_to_use_only_part_of_physical/). Just note, you would want to attach the magnifier to the left... not the right. You want to block off the broken bit.

> Use the Magnifier utility built into Windows.

> The magnifier is included as an Ease of Access Accessory to allow people with poor eyesight to use Windows more easily, but it can also be used to block off a portion of the desktop. Assuming you're using Windows 7, you open it up, click the "Views" menu and change it to "Docked", then attach the dock to the right side of your screen. It might take some fiddling, but you can resize the docked magnifier to cover the exact size of the blacked-out portion of your monitor.

> Then, when you maximize or split windows, Windows will treat the edge of the docked magnifier like it's the edge of the screen. You don't get your clock back, but it might be the best solution. You can kind of see the effect in [this video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=0u0ZwLaRGsc). When the instructor opens the Magnifier in docked mode, the Ease of Access window resizes itself to be under the dock, because now as far as Windows is concerned, that's the size of your desktop.

3. Reduce Desktop aspect ratio. This will yield black bars on both sides of the screen, but may be better than nothing if 1 and 2 don't pan out.

Each of these works best in different scenarios. I think number 2 will probably be best in your case, but the others might as well.

Comment: Number 2 works like a charm! But since, as you said, this fix is indeed a bit clunky, I'll leave the question open for a few hours more before marking yours as the answer in case someone has another take on this. Thank you!

Also, quick question about your research: what were your findings on Display Changer II? For me it feels like it does have the power to do the fix, but I may be breaking some rules about display settings that I don't know about...

Comment: I couldn't say for sure... I haven't used it personally. I think your observation is very true.... I am hesitant to use anything that gives off the sense of being "home made" and powerful. Not that there aren't some good indie solutions, I just dont have the risk appetite to justify such things. I will use clunky fixes until a certified-safe one presents itself.

Comment: I should add: this doesn't work for fullscreen apps