# Ignore damaged part of screen

Tags: display, windows-11

One of my kids recently squashed my laptop and damaged the screen.  Specifically, the rightmost 20% or so of the screen is all vertical stripes and inverted colors.  I'm going to get it repaired or replaced, but in the meantime... is there a way to "turn off" that portion of the screen?  In other words, to redefine the boundary of the screen at the point where it works?  Ideally I'd like to be able to maximize a window on that monitor and have it fill only the working portion.

Comment: On linux you could configure X11 via xrandr to do that. I've just seen a reddit post of someone doing that with a broken screen a few days ago. On windows not so much.

Comment: Maybe PowerToys FancyZones could help, but I'm not sure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use workarounds for a broken LCD screen? Is there such a thing as valid aspect ratios?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543241/how-to-use-workarounds-for-a-broken-lcd-screen-is-there-such-a-thing-as-valid-a) The second option in the answer there, the Magnifier tool in Windows might work for you. As noted by OP, it does not work for fullscreen applications though

Answer (score 1):

You could use software that will constrain your windows to exist inside
a part of the screen.

Some free products that I know of :

- [Microsoft PowerToys](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/microsoft-powertoys/XP89DCGQ3K6VLD)
  includes a utility called
  [FancyZones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones)
  that creates a grid on the screen into which you can drag any window.
- The old
  [DesktopCoral](https://www.donationcoder.com/software/mouser/other-windows-apps/desktopcoral)
  acts like an invisible resizeable docking bar positioned on to any
  side of the desktop that shields its area of your desktop from other
  applications.

Comment: [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/) can reserve customizable areas next to screen borders too.